# .htaccess Causing Internal / Forbidden Server Error

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file is causing an internal server error / forbidden

Heres the code:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule 
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?source=$1 [NC]
```

All I want is when someone goes to mysite.com/item, it really goes to mysite.com/index.php?source=item

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an orphan `RewriteRule` before actual rule.

Change your code to:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?source=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Plus 1 to you sir, this was driving me mad